# neo4j why is start node not found in result set?

Tags: neo4j, match, cypher

I haven't found a question about this or found any comment in the Neo4j manual.

This query returns the start node:

```
start n = node:node_auto_index(subject_id='A1')
match (n)-[]->()<-[]-(n)
return distinct n.subject_id;
==> +--------------+
==> | n.subject_id |
==> +--------------+
==> | "A1" |
==> +--------------+
==> 1 row
```

but this query does not return the start node.  Is there any way to make it return the start node along with with other matching nodes?

```
start n = node:node_auto_index(subject_id='A1')
match (n)-[]->()<-[]-(s)
where s.subject_id = 'A1'
return distinct s.subject_id;
==> +--------------+
==> | s.subject_id |
==> +--------------+
==> +--------------+
==> 0 row
```

Just to be sure I have the syntax right, the previous query works on nodes other than the start node:

```
start n = node:node_auto_index(subject_id='A1')
match (n)-[]->()<-[]-(s)
where s.subject_id = 'B2'
return distinct s.subject_id;
==> +--------------+
==> | s.subject_id |
==> +--------------+
==> | "B2" |
==> +--------------+
==> 1 row
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you ran into identifier uniqueness in cypher paths.

In the same path two different identifiers (if not bound upfront) won't point to the same node.

In your fist example both sides of the path are bound (to the same node) and in the last example you have two different nodes, one bound to `n` the other bound to `s`.

In the second example you would end up with the same node being bound to `n` and `s`, which cypher does not do in a path.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.  It's challenging to break out of the relational viewpoint.